# gRPC for C++ on Ubuntu - protoc-gen-grpc error

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

I'm trying to use gRPC for a project and keep running into the following trouble: when generating grpc headers, [the manual I can see](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) instructs to execute

```
/usr/src/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/protobuf/protoc --proto_path=. --grpc_out=../.build/protocol \
 --plugin=protoc_gen_grpc=/usr/src/grpc/cmake/build/grpc_cpp_plugin ./Test.proto
```

All referenced files and folders exist, `grpc_cpp_plugin` is built with cmake from gRPC sources (along with the protobuf executable), lies in the provided directory and has -x- permissions. However, running the command results in

```
protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

error. This problem is observed in both Ubuntu and MinGW under Windows. The version for Windows (obtained via vcpkg) does execute the similar command successfully. The command

```
/usr/src/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/protobuf/protoc --proto_path=. --cpp_out=../.build/protocol ./Test.proto
```

executes without any problems.

Ideas about what I'm doing wrong and/or how I can obtain more detailed diagnostic and/or how I can build gRPC C++ files with some other command would be appreciated.

Comment: Once you build protoc-gen-grpc, add the location to PATH like it says.  In windows, reason it works is probably caused by where the executable ended up. Search out where that thing lives if you are sure you have it. You may also have to chmod to give it executable permissions (again like the print says)

Comment: Executing `PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/grpc/cmake/build` and then either the same command or with `--plugin=protoc_gen_grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin` yields the same result. (As a sanity check, executing `grpc_cpp_plugin` after this PATH edit launches the plugin.)

Comment: Try `chmod +e /usr/src/grpc/cmake/build/protoc-gen-grpc` if that says it doesn't exist, you will have to find where that `protoc-gen-grpc` lives.  If you can't, then figure out how to build it.

Comment: There is no file called `protoc-gen-grpc`, nor, to the best of my understanding, there should exist one (it certainly isn't generated when building gRPC through any means I've tried). `grpc_cpp_plugin` already has permissions `-rwxrwxr-x`. `+e` isn't a valid `chmod` option or MODE, at least on my system.

Comment: Sorry my bad it's +x. (If -e something is file exists...) But you got the gist of your problem.  You will need such a file, and one does not exist, if it did exist, it must be marked executable.  Find the solution and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Abel Do you _know_ something about that? Because my best understanding of the "double equality" `--plugin=protoc_gen_grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin` is that it means that the _third_ term must be an executable used as a plugin. It certainly worked that way on Windows (where I previously scanned all disk assuming that I needed a file called `protoc-gen-grpc*` and so I am certain there was none; despite that, the generator worked). Also, there is no target called `protoc-gen-grpc` in gRPC makefiles, as far as I can see - this combination of symbols exists _only_ as `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=...`.

Comment: I think I see your problem.  `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=...` not `--plugin=protoc_gen_...` - use dash, not underscore.

Comment: ... It did ideed fix the issue. I'm not sure whether I feel stupid, annoyed, relieved or some combination of the three. Either way, thank for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14237276/abel) pointed out in the comments, my issue was simply a matter of attention (I wrote `protoc_gen_grpc` instead of `protoc-gen-grpc`). Still, since I went through a number of questions and articles before successfully building and using gRPC for C++, might as well summarize it here for people dealing with the same issues. (Notice the date of the post, it may become outdated in the future.)

### Documentation

There are several instructions saying roughly the same things with minor differences. For example, [Quick start](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart) recommends using CMake, but the [github BUILDING.md it links](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) says Bazel is preferable. In addition there is a separate [github instruction for C++](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp/README.md) that has platforms support table and advice for using CMake.

### gRPC for Windows (MSVC)

- Quick start does not cover Windows at all. The best practical option at the time seems to be using [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) - when installing gRPC it will also pick up all dependencies (like zlib and Abseil) and should compile all that without trouble.
- If, for whatever reason, you decide to go the long way described in BUILDING.md, some potentially useful things about building with CMake:

  - Install CMake GUI and use "Configure". It will clearly show all meaningful flags and configuration-time warnings.
  - *Do not* "Open Project" from GUI, though. For whatever reason Visual Studio by default outputs files into wrong folders. Use knowledge from GUI to write the correct console command.
  - The build sequence is [Abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/CMake/README.md) - [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/README.md) - gRPC. You can ignore Google tests as Abseil dependency but it's important that Abseil is build corresponding to its CMakeLists.txt otherwise protobuf build will fail.
- Either way, you should have `protoc.exe` (from protobuf) and `grpc_cpp_plugin.exe` (in `tools\grpc` or `INSTALL_BIN_DIR` of gRPC build). With that, you can compile `.proto` file(s), like so:

  ```
   %PROTO_COMPILER% --proto_path=. --grpc_out=..\build\protocol --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=%PROTO_GRPC_PLUGIN% .\MyFile.proto
   %PROTO_COMPILER% --proto_path=. --cpp_out=..\build\protocol .\MyFile.proto
  ```
- This assumes `%PROTO_GRPC_PLUGIN%` is an absolute path to the `grpc_cpp_plugin.exe` and does not contain spaces or non-ASCII characters. Add quotes in case of the former and either rename directories or use [subst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) for the latter. `%PROTO_COMPILER%`, similarly, is a path to the `protoc.exe`.
- One somewhat confusing thing here is that if the compiler can't find the plugin file for *any* reason, it will produce a misleading diagnostic `protoc-gen-grpc: program not found or is not executable`. *There is no file named `protoc-gen-rpc` in this toolchain.*
- To compile the project using this protocol you'll need to do the following (CMake may be capable of doing this neatly by instructions like `find_package` but in case of any problems you should be able to do this by hand):

  - add `\include` folders of Abseil, protobuf and gRPC to your project includes paths;
  - add `\lib` or `\debug\lib` folders (depending on your build type, MSVC will produce linker errors if you try to link the wrong version, at least for gRPC) of Abseil, protobuf, gRPC, UPB, C-Ares, Re2, zlib and OpenSSL to your linker paths (you need only `abseil_dll.lib` from Abseil and only a subset of gRPC libs);
  - copy `abseil_dll.dll`, `cares.dll`, `libprotobuf.dll` and `zlib1.dll` (or their debug versions, depending on your build type) to your executable folder or make them otherwise available.

### gRPC for Linux (g++)

- This works much easier, simply following instructions from BUILDING.md compiles everything (requires creating hardlinks, don't try to build on a network drive or in a shared folder).
- `protoc` executable should be in `cmake/build/third_party/protobuf/` subfolder of `gRPC`, C++ plugin in `cmake/build/`. `.proto` compilation commands are similar (see the post for an example).